VS not searching for CMakeLists.txt in subfolders
I have a main folder with multiple subfolders, each with its own project and CMakeLists.txt. When I open VS in a specific project folder, it recognises it as a CMake project and I can configure it. When I open the top-level directory, VS doesn't search for CMakeLists.txt in the sub-directories and I can't configure any project, no configuration is found. How do I fix this?
VS: No Configurations
This is not an issue in VSCode or for my colleague, who works on exactly the same files and folders. I use VSP 2022, he uses 2019.
I made the following CMakeLists.txt in the top-level directory:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

project(myProject)

add_subdirectory(dir1) 
add_subdirectory(dir2) 
add_subdirectory(dir3)

...but this didn't solve the problem.

What is the error message saying?

Hi, there is no error message, just no configurations available.
